# non-exponential family probability distributions and their uses

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I was actually trying to find information on non-exponential family probability distributions. So many of the distributions that we study in statistics are members of an exponential family of distributions. But this leads to the natural question of whether there exist sets of distributions that are not members of an exponential family? I could not find any references to these.

Does anyone know of distributions that are not members of an exponential family? Also, what are the applications for these types of distributions? Where are they used?

Thanks.

Comment: Please replace "the exponential family" by "an exponential family", three times.

Comment: grammar corrected.

Comment: @Xi'an Even considering my comment to hejseb's answer below?

Comment: @Xi'an Which is perfectly in agreement with the definition of an exponential family.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're referring to distributions with unbounded tails. That rules out uniform, beta and so forth. The exponential distributions are a good watermark in the distributions manifold, splitting it into 3 subspaces: exponential, subexponential and superexponential. Examples of each are:

Exponential: Normal

Superexponential:

Subexponential: Lévy, Cauchy, Student t, Pareto, Generalised Pareto, Weibull, Burr, Lognormal, Log-Cauchy, Log-Gamma

The latter, the fat-tailed distributions, are particularly useful to Extreme Value Theory and when applied to the measurement of low-frequency/high-impact risks, such as in operational risk.

Comment: Perhaps you could also explain where there are used?

Comment: There seem to be a conflation of two apparently unrelated uses of the adjective "exponential". If there is any relation between a family of distribution being an exponential family and its members having certain tail behaviour, it does not seem as straightforward as you outline. More is discussed here https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/444528 .

Answer (score 5):

A simple example is the uniform distribution, which is not a member of the exponential family. Neither is Student's $t$. I would also guess that the F distribution is not a member either (though I haven't checked).

The $t$-test is, as I'm guessing you know, very well used and evidently distributions that do not belong to the exponential family are still widely used. The uniform distribution is common too, perhaps due to its simplicity. While not so often used in different tests, it's of course still used (quite often as a prior in Bayesian applications, for instance).

Comment: Every uniform distribution is very much a member of **an** exponential family.

Comment: @Xi'an Identifying probability distributions with their density with respect to the Lebesgue measure, the uniform distribution on $(0,1)$ is a member of the family $(f_\theta)_{\theta>0}$ where, for every $\theta>0$, $$f_\theta(x)=\theta x^{\theta-1}\,\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}$$ The family $(f_\theta)_{\theta>0}$ is an exponential family (using the standardest definition of the term) since, for every $\theta>0$,  $$f_\theta(x)=h(x)\exp(a(\theta)g(x)+b(\theta))$$ with $$h(x)=\mathbf 1_{0<x<1}\quad a(\theta)=\theta-1\quad g(x)=\log x\quad b(\theta)=\log\theta$$ Hence my first comment above.

Comment: @Xi'an Yes. But since nobody specified the condition that a uniform distribution should be a member of a family of uniform distributions, the example seems perfectly legit. If they do specify the condition, your first comment to me applies. If they do not, it is not an objection.

Comment: @Did : A uniform distribution in the interval [0,$\theta$] doesn't belong to exponential family. However, a uniform distribution over [0,$a$], where '$a$' is a constant, belongs to exponential family.

Comment: @AnverHisham Sorry but did you even try to read my comment? Or is yours just random noise?

Answer (score 2):

There are many non-exponential families like the uniform, Cauchy, t-distributions, generalized Gaussian, etc.
However, you can always approximate closely any smooth distribution by one exponential family. These are dense models. See
http://arxiv.org/abs/0911.4863
and also
k-MLE for mixtures of generalized Gaussians
http://www.lix.polytechnique.fr/~schwander/articles/icpr2012.pdf

In other words, location-scale, elliptical, exponential families and heavy-tailed distributions are important equally.

Comment: I do not understand "you can always approximate closely any smooth distribution by one exponential family". Every distribution is a member of some exponential families, no?